# Can't we use 2 different chrome browser using different port?

Tags: selenium-chromedriver, robotframework, browser-automation, webautomation

I started two chrome using

```
start chrome --remote-debugging-port=9222
start chrome --remote-debugging-port=9223
```

I tried connecting to these browsers  using rpaframework keyword:

```
RPA.Browser.Selenium.Attach Chrome Browser   9222   alias=site1
RPA.Browser.Selenium.Go To  https://google.com
RPA.Browser.Selenium.Attach Chrome Browser    9223  alias=site2
RPA.Browser.Selenium.Go To  https://duckduckgo.com
```

But this is not working, first one is getting connected but the second one is waiting for sometime and then shows error

> failed with: WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: cannot
> connect to chrome at localhost:9222 from chrome not reachable
>
> Blockquote

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Selenium Grid**.

> Create a Hub:

```
java -jar sel.jar -role hub -port 9000
```

> Create as many Node you need.

You can run chrome on each node:

```
java -Dwebdriver.gecko.driver="/driver/geckodriver" -sel.jar -role webdriver -hub http://localhost:9000/grid/register -port 9001

java -Dwebdriver.gecko.driver="/driver/geckodriver" -sel.jar -role webdriver -hub http://localhost:9000/grid/register -port 9002
```

You can check the nodes using below:

```
http://localhost:9000/grid/console
```